# Angularjs, undefined data returned from a Factory

Tags: angularjs

Just a quick question.

I have this **`factory`**:

```
 angular.module('app.services').factory('DatabaseFactory', 
 function($log, $q, DB_CONFIG, CATEGORY_CONFIG, $http, $webSql) {
  var self = this;
  self.db = null;

  self.init = function() {
    self.db = $webSql.openDatabase (DB_CONFIG.name, '1.0', 'database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    self.db.createTable('QuestionIndex', {
      'id':{
        'type': 'INTEGER',
        'null': 'NOT NULL', // default is 'NULL' (if not defined)
        'primary': true, // primary
        'auto_increment': true // auto increment
      },
      'question_id': {
        'type': 'INTEGER'
      },
      'oltre': {
        'type': 'INTEGER'
      },
      'section_id': {
        'type': 'INTEGER'
      },
      'errors_count': {
        'type': 'INTEGER'
      },
      'done_count': {
        'type': 'INTEGER'
      }

    }); 

  };

  self.getAll = function() { 
    self.db.select('QuestionIndex',{"oltre":'IS NOT NULL'}).then(function(results) {
      var records = [];
      for(var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
        records.push(results.rows.item(i));
      };
      $log.info(records); 
      return records;
    }); 
  };

  return self;

});
```

I'm injecting this factory in another factory and I must retrieve the data calling `getAll`function.

```
angular.module('app.services')
  .factory('QuizCreate', ['DatabaseFactory','$log', function(DatabaseFactory,$log){
    self.generateQuiz = function() {
      $log.info(DatabaseFactory.getAll());
    };
    return self;
  }]);
```

The first log entry return me all the objects, the query is working fine. I can't understand why my the second log return me `undefined`.

Why I can't return my data from the first Factory?

Comment: It's running asynchronously. If you return `self.db.select` it would return you a promise (I assume) which you could then do something with. It's returning `undefined` because the `return` statement isn't hit before the `$log.info` executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It (the database query) is running asynchronously, so the `return` statement inside your `.then()` is not being hit before the `$log.info` executes.

I would modify it as follows:

DatabaseFactory:

```
self.getAll = function() { 
    return self.db.select('QuestionIndex',{"oltre":'IS NOT NULL'}).then(function(results) {
      var records = [];
      for(var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
        records.push(results.rows.item(i));
      };
      $log.info(records); 
      return records;
    }); 
  };
```

QuizCreate Factory

```
self.generateQuiz = function() {
      DatabaseFactory.getAll().then(function(result){
        $log.info(result);
      });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `DatabaseFactory.init()`? I don't see it being called anywhere